# Print Preview White Border around image in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, print-css

Firefox and IE display the border around image while doing print preview. It is a simple page with two div each div contains one image width of 400px and the container div is 800px. I do not want the white border in between the two images which I am getting while doing print preview. Is there anything I am doing wrong here?? (in chrome it does not display the white border.)

I have tried this code also for print css but no luck..

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.test{float:none;display:inline;  border:none;}
img{border:0;}
</style>
```

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
.test{float:left; display:inline; border:none;}
</style>
</head>

 <body>
 <div style="width:800px;margin:0px auto;">
 <div class="test" style="float:left;width:400px;">
 <img src="1334300111712.jpg">
 </div>
 <div class="test" style="float:left;width:400px;">
<img src="1334300115318.jpg">
 </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this CSS:

```
img { border: 0; }
```